# Apache v2.4 is serving HTTP over port 443 aka enable https in apache2 with vhosts

Tags: apache2, ssl, virtualhost, https

I am running into this trouble on Ubuntu 20.04.

It looks a lot like a number of similar ones but, after hours of attempts it turned out it is not the usual one.

I used `certbot --apache` to add HTTPS to one of my working websites on my server.
I asked to get automatic redirection to HTTPS. All went apparently OK.
I also ran `a2enmod ssl; a2nsite default-ssl.conf` to enable SSL module and restarted apache2.

In the logs it seems certificates are read:

```
[ssl:info] [pid 4187632] AH02568: Certificate and private key mysite.com:443:0 configured from /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com/fullchain.pem and /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com/privkey.pem
```

I also found this but cannot find enough documentation about it:

```
 [headers:debug] [pid 4188047] mod_headers.c(899): AH01503: headers: ap_headers_error_filter()
```

What happens in the end is that apache2 is listening on port 443, but is serving HTTP over that port once the redirection happens. Of course browsers don't work and spit out errors like:

```
This site can’t provide a secure connection
mysite.com sent an invalid response.
ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

And nothing else.

From another server I can do these two simple tests:

```
$ nmap -A -Pn -p 443 mysite.com.
Nmap scan report for mysite.com. (1.2.3.4)
Host is up (0.044s latency).
Other addresses for mysite.com. (not scanned): 1234:1234:123:1234::
rDNS record for 1.2.3.4: host1.hosting.net

PORT    STATE SERVICE VERSION
443/tcp open  http    Apache httpd 2.4.41
|_http-server-header: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu)
|_http-title: Did not follow redirect to https://mysite.com/
Service Info: Host: mysite.com

Service detection performed. Please report any incorrect results at https://nmap.org/submit/ .
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 7.64 seconds
```

and

```
$ wget -v -v -v https://mysite.com/
--2024-01-15 16:42:45--  https://mysite.com/
Loaded CA certificate '/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt'
Resolving mysite.com (mysite.com)... 1.2.3.4, 1234:1234:123:1234::
Connecting to mysite.com (mysite.com)|1.2.3.4|:443... connected.
GnuTLS: An unexpected TLS packet was received.
Unable to establish SSL connection.
```

These confirm my diagnosis (HTTP over port 443) and that there is no firewall blocking any content.

Any hint?

My (main) configuration bits are here below.

All other file (`000-default.conf` and `default-ssl.conf`) are default from Ubuntu 20.04 install.

`ports.conf` :

```
# If you just change the port or add more ports here, you will likely also
# have to change the VirtualHost statement in
# /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

Listen 80

<IfModule ssl_module>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

`mysite.conf`

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
  ServerName  mysite.com
  ServerAlias  www.mysite.com
  ServerAdmin me@mysite.com
  DocumentRoot /home/fe/public_html

  <Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Credentials, please"
    AuthUserFile /home/fe/.htpasswd
    Require valid-user
  </Directory>

  ScriptAlias /x/ /home/fe/cgi/
  <Directory "/home/fe/cgi">
    Options ExecCGI
    SetHandler cgi-script
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mysite-error.log
  LogLevel debug
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mysite-access.log combined
  <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
  </FilesMatch>
  <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
  </Directory>
  BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
    nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
    downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
  # MSIE 7 and newer should be able to use keepalive
  BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =site.mysite.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

Last three lines have been added by `certbot`.

`mysite-le-ssl.conf`

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
 <VirtualHost _default_:443>
  ServerName  mysite.com
  ServerAlias  www.mysite.com
  ServerAdmin me@mysite.com
  DocumentRoot /home/fe/public_html

  <Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Credentials, please"
    AuthUserFile /home/fe/.htpasswd
    Require valid-user
  </Directory>

  ScriptAlias /x/ /home/fe/cgi/
  <Directory "/home/fe/cgi">
    Options ExecCGI
    SetHandler cgi-script
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mysite-error.log
  LogLevel debug
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mysite-access.log combined
  <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
  </FilesMatch>
  <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
  </Directory>
  BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
    nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
    downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
  # MSIE 7 and newer should be able to use keepalive
  BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown

  SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com/fullchain.pem
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com/privkey.pem
  Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
  </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I "fixed" the configuration by myself, with a bit of luck.

The issue seems to have been caused by the default configuration Ubuntu is shipping with Apache v2.x.

After enabling the needed modules with something like

```
sudo a2enmod ssl
sudo a2enmod headers
sudo a2enmod socache_shmcb
```

I also enabled the "*default SSL site*" with

```
sudo a2ensite default-ssl
```

Then added my own stuff in the `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` directory.

I added something like:

```
01-mysite.conf
02-other.conf
03-thistoo.conf
```

After running `certbot --apache` the directory content became:

```
01-mysite-le-ssl.conf
01-mysite.conf
02-other-le-ssl.conf
02-other.conf
03-thistoo-le-ssl.conf
03-thistoo.conf
```

The problem came from the fact that the "*default SSL site*" configuration file is called `default-ssl.conf`  while the "*default plaintext site*" configuration is called `000-default.conf` .

In my specific case, then, `default-ssl.conf` was the last one to be read by Apache v2.x from the `sites-enabled` directory:

```
000-default.conf
01-mysite-le-ssl.conf
01-mysite.conf
02-other-le-ssl.conf
02-other.conf
03-thistoo-le-ssl.conf
03-thistoo.conf
default-ssl.conf
```

By "**simply**" renaming `default-ssl.conf` to `000-default-ssl.conf` I started having things working, after a mandatory reload: `systemctl apache2 reload; systemct apache2 status`!

The very same `nmap` command seen in the question now returns the expected results:

```
$ nmap -A -Pn -p 443 mysite.com.
Nmap scan report for mysite.com. (1.2.3.4)
Host is up (0.044s latency).
Other addresses for mysite.com. (not scanned): 1234:1234:123:1234::
rDNS record for 1.2.3.4: host1.hosting.net

PORT    STATE SERVICE  VERSION
443/tcp open  ssl/http Apache httpd 2.4.41
| tls-alpn: 
|_  http/1.1
|_http-title: 421 Misdirected Request
|_http-server-header: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu)
|_ssl-date: TLS randomness does not represent time
| ssl-cert: Subject: commonName=host1
| Subject Alternative Name: DNS:host1
| Not valid before: 2022-11-06T10:22:12
|_Not valid after:  2032-11-03T10:22:12
Service Info: Host: 127.0.0.1

Service detection performed. Please report any incorrect results at https://nmap.org/submit/ .
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 15.74 seconds
```

It seems `nmap` doesn't know how to place a well-formed HTTPS SNI request.

But now we have: `443/tcp open  ssl/http Apache httpd 2.4.41` : now it's **`ssl/http`**, not just **`http`**!

Lesson learned: with SSL/TLS and SNI, order matters. And a lot too!

As a very minor side note, I cleaned up the non-SSL (aka "HTTP") configuration file like this:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
  ServerName  mysite.com # <-----------------.
  RewriteEngine on #                         | THE SAME
  RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =mysite.com # <-'
  RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

All other configuration stuff has been moved into the SSL-enabled configuration. Simple and effective!

I really hope this will help others.